# python code to connect to sftp server

Tags: python

I found this code to connect to remote sftp server with the help of username ,password and host but i also need to include the port number, can any one let em know how to include the port number in this code and also for this piece of code
'parmiko.util.log_to_file(log_filename)' what should i hard code for log_filename ??
 Iam runnign this code in unix environment.

```
import os
import paramiko
server, username, password = ('host', 'username', 'password')   
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  
parmiko.util.log_to_file(log_filename)    
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

' #In case the server's key is unknown,'
#we will be adding it automatically to the list of known hosts 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))   

#Loads the user's local known host file  
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password) 
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls /tmp') 

print "output", ssh_stdout.read() #Reading output of the executed co'mmand 
error = ssh_stderr.read()  

#Reading the error stream of the executed command
print "err", error, len(error) 

#Transfering files to and from the remote machine' 
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()   
'sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)'
sftp.put(local_path, remote_path) 
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `port=` named argument to the ssh.connect() method. See the [manual](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SSHClient-class.html#connect)

Example:

```
ssh.connect(server, port=portnumber, username=username, password=password)
```

Comment: Got there a second before I did :P +1