# Executing Python to write .csv file to remote directory

Tags: python, csv, remote-access, remote-server

I have a script that processes downloaded log files into csv's per some parsing logic.

I want to write those csv's to a remote directory on a different server.  This is due to space constraints on the server where I execute the script.

I have tried a few variations of the below script but I just cant seem to figure this out.  I understand "SFTP" and "SSH" commands but I am not sure if that is the right approach in this use case.(I have all the keys and stuff setup to allow for remote connections between the servers)

```
import os
import re
import string
import csv
import gzip
import extract5
import pickle
import shutil
import pygeoip

def conn():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.connect(XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX.XXXXXXXX.COM, username=XXXXXXX)
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd_to_execute)
    return conn(self:%s % (['cd /fs/fs01/crmdata/SYWR/AAM/AAM_Master/'])

downloadroot = '/opt/admin/AAM_Scripts/'
outgoing = conn

for sfile in os.listdir(downloadroot):
    if sfile.endswith('gz'):
        oname = sfile[sfile.find('AAM'):]
        extract5.process(downloadroot,sfile,oname,outgoing)

#delete download dictionary and pickle
for date in os.listdir(downloadroot):
    #match = re.match('(\d{4})[/.-](\d{2})[/,-](\d{2})$', date)
    if date.find('AAM_CDF_1181_') > 0:
        os.remove('%s%s' % (downloadroot, date))

os.remove('%sdownload.pkl' % (downloadroot))
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?  I am on the right path or is my approach completely off.  I would love some thoughts behind how or if I can accomplish this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run this? Also, does your ssh not have a password?

Comment: I created "Keys" so I don't need a password to perform SSH.  I don't get any errors but the csv's get written on the script dir and not the remote with a weird title "function conn at 0Xx29656"

Comment: So this might not help at all, but maybe add parenthesis after "outgoing = conn" so it becomes "outgoing = conn()". Also in a different post, it was mentioned that there is a port= named argument to the ssh.connect() method. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217887/python-code-to-connect-to-sftp-server